# data structure for retrieving words inside strings

Tags: string, data-structures, matching

I made this question yesterday (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992011/data-structure-for-efficent-time-and-space-searching-of-strings-with-substrings) but I realized that maybe this approach is wrong.

What I need should be a data structure allowing me to store strings and retrieve all of them having a common word inside. Unfortunately i can't wait the user has typed all a word but I have to rely on a prefix.

For example if I have the strings "This is a string inside the structure" and "Binary tree data structure" and as input a prefix like "stru" both of them must be in the output.

is there any useful approach?

Comment: perhaps look up `trie` : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: Yes it was the first data structure I thought but you have as output only the strings that begin with the prefix given in input... Should I modify the structure in such a way?

Comment: You aren't limited in what you store in the trie. Storing all suffixes is also an option.http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree

Answer (score 1):

This is going to depend in large part how many strings you have in the list. If your list isn't *huge*, then you can do a simple sequential search when the user enters the first character, and then search the results of that search for subsequent searches.

Consider, for example, if you have 1,000 strings in the list and the user types `'s'`. You search the original list and end up with a list of 623 words that contain that letter. Call that list `S`.

The user then types `'t'` and you search `S` for the substring `"st"`. Call the result `ST`.

You continue in this manner, doing sequential searches and paring your list. It looks something like this:

```
// search in initial list of strings for first character
results = new list
for each string in list
    if string.Contains("s")
        Add string to results

// for subsequent characters the user types
newResults = new list
for each string in results
    if string.Contains("st")
        Add string to newResults
results = newResults
```

The list will get very small pretty fast. When you consider that the most common bigram in the English language, "th", occurs in about 3.8% of words, it's very likely that after just two characters typed you'll have fewer than 40 items in your list out of the starting 1,000. Sequential search on that is going to be *very* fast. It will take longer to display the results to the user than it will take to search the list.

Even if your initial list of strings has 1 million items, the user probably won't notice a delay on the first character typed. That's especially true if you display results incrementally rather than waiting for the entire list to be searched before displaying anything.

You could potentially speed things up by creating an index of first characters. That is, create a dictionary entry for every character that's contained in the list of strings. It would be `Dictionary<char, List<string>>`. So if the user types `'s'`, you get the list:

```
List<string> startingList = _dict['s'];
```

Then you use the previous algorithm, starting with that list.

That can speed your initial search, but it's going to take a lot of memory. It's not worth doing unless you have a very large list of initial strings.

See [Know when to stop optimizing](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/07/17/know-when-to-stop-optimizing/) for a bit more detail.

### Additional info

If you're dealing with a huge number of strings, you probably should build a prefix tree, but limit its depth. For example, build a prefix tree that goes to a maximum depth of 3 or 4 characters, and then use the sequential approach I show above. That will take a lot less memory than a full prefix tree, and should perform very well. By the time you get to four characters, the number of lines that contain that substring should be pretty small.

You should write code to analyze the n-gram counts in your data. See how many different bigrams you have and the maximum number of lines that match a bigram. Do the same with trigrams, 4-grams, etc. to determine where your cutoff should be. For example, if you find that no 4-gram has more than 1,000 matching lines, then you probably should limit your prefix tree to four levels and use the sequential technique after that. There's really no need to create a full prefix tree after that. Although you *could* create a full prefix tree and then collapse the hapaxes into single nodes. What you end up with is essentially a directed acyclic word graph.

Remember, though, that you're responding to user input. So saving a few milliseconds isn't all that important. A user isn't going to notice the difference between a 20 millisecond response time and a 5 millisecond response time. The code doesn't have to be "as fast as possible," but rather "fast enough* for the user. If you keep that in mind, you can create a much simpler solution that uses a lot less memory.

Comment: I think your reasoning is right. Never use sophisticated data structure when it's not needed. Unfortunately I have to deal with a huge number of strings. I'm thinking to use an hybrid approach with a prefix/radix tree storing all the terms inside the strings and for each term I have the list of string containing it. Does it make sense?

Comment: It seems a really nice approach! I will try this one :)